# Using Mapbox expressions to paint color depending on two different data fields

Tags: mapbox, vector-layer, mapbox-gl

I'm visualizing geospatial data that has an attribute table with fields like this:

```
id | main_type | sub_type
```

In Mapbox GL, I can use expressions to paint the polygons according to main_type:

```
                "paint": {
                    "fill-color": [
                        "match",
                        [
                            "get",
                            "main_type"
                        ],
                        "A",
                        "#20707b",
                        "B",
                        "#1f8f76",
                        "C",
                        "#2f3776",
                        "X",
                        "#371865",
                        "rgba(255,255,255,0)"
                    ]
                }
```

But I am interested in painting the sub_types of X, say E, F, G as well, so what I really want to do is something like:

```
                "paint": {
                    "fill-color": [
                        "match",
                        [
                            "get",
                            "main_type"
                        ],
                        "A",
                        "#20707b",
                        "B",
                        "#1f8f76",
                        "C",
                        "#2f3776",
                        "rgba(255,255,255,0)",

                        "match",
                        [
                            "get",
                            "sub_type"
                        ],
                        "E",
                        "#FF0000",
                        "F",
                        "#00FF00",
                        "G",
                        "#0000FF",
                        "rgba(255,255,255,0)"
                    ]
                },
```

How can I do this using Mapbox expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by nesting the subtypes in the default case:

```
           "paint": {
                "fill-color": [
                        "match",
                            [
                                "get",
                                "main_type"
                            ],
                            "A",
                            "#20707b",
                            "B",
                            "#1f8f76",
                            "C",
                            "#2f3776",
                            [ 
                                "match",
                                    [
                                        "get",
                                        "sub_type"
                                    ],
                                    "E",
                                    "#FF0000",
                                    "F",
                                    "#00FF00",
                                    "G",
                                    "#0000FF",
                                    "rgba(255,255,255,0)"
                            ]
                    ]
            }
```